# How to create blocks in theme app extension? [blocks/carousel.liquid] Invalid tag 'schema': unknown key 'blocks'

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app, shopify-template

guys I'm new to Shopify development. I have created a theme app extension and want to upload image. But I want images to be dynamic like we choose for collections and products in shopify themes.

I have tried to create blocks by looking some of predefined code for slideshow and collections list.

Here is what I tried. I have created theme app extension and created a carousel.liquid file where I wrote the code mention below in scheme tag.

`{% schema %} { "name":"Carousel_ext", "target":"section", "blocks":[ { "type":"@app", "name":"Images", "limit":5, "settings":[ { "type":"image_picker", "id":"image", "label":"t:sections.Carousel_ext.blocks.slide.settings.image.label" } ] } ] } {% endschema %}`

Apart this I have created two files in locales, that are    en.default.json     and       en.default.schema.json

en.default.json contains the code mentioned below
`{ "carousel_ext": { "slide":"Slide" }      }`

And, en.default.schema.json contains the code shown below

`{

"Carousel_ext": {
"name": "Carousel_ext",
"blocks": {
"slide": {
"name": "Slide",
"settings": {
"image": {
"label": "Image"
}
}
}
}
}
}`

I was expecting that left side after adding theme-app-extension, the extension provides the option to upload the image.

but I'm getting the error after running "npm run deploy" command that is shown below:

C:\Users\Sumesh Kumar\Hempyar-Carousel\hempyar\carousel-extension\extensions\theme-app-extension>npm run deploy

> theme-app@1.0.0 deploy
> shopify app deploy

?  Make the following changes to your extensions in Shopify Partners?
✔  Yes, deploy to push changes

Deploying your work to Shopify Partners. It will be part of hempyar-extension

theme_extensions │ Running theme check on your Theme app extension...
theme_extensions │ Checking C:/Users/Sumesh
Kumar/Hempyar-Carousel/hempyar/carousel-extension/extensions/theme-app-extension ...
theme_extensions │ blocks/carousel.liquid:15: suggestion: LiquidTag: Use {% liquid ... %} to write
multiple tags.
theme_extensions │     {% for product in all_products.products %}
theme_extensions │        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
theme_extensions │
theme_extensions │ blocks/carousel.liquid:37: style: SpaceInsideBraces: Space missing after '|'.
theme_extensions │     
theme_extensions │                                 ^^
theme_extensions │
theme_extensions │ blocks/carousel.liquid:37: style: SpaceInsideBraces: Space missing before '|'.
theme_extensions │     
theme_extensions │                                 ^
theme_extensions │
theme_extensions │ blocks/carousel.liquid:37: style: SpaceInsideBraces: Space missing after '{{'.
theme_extensions │     
theme_extensions │                    ^
theme_extensions │
theme_extensions │ blocks/carousel.liquid:5: suggestion: UnusedAssign: `product_number` is never used.
theme_extensions │     {% assign product_number = all_products.all_products_count %}
theme_extensions │        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
theme_extensions │
theme_extensions │ blocks/carousel.liquid:24: suggestion: DeprecatedFilter: Deprecated filter `img_url`,
consider using `image_url`.
theme_extensions │     {% assign allimages = product.featured_image | img_url | append: ',' | append:
allimages %}
theme_extensions │                                                    ^^^^^^^^
theme_extensions │
theme_extensions │ blocks/carousel.liquid:9: suggestion: ImgLazyLoading: Add a loading="lazy" attribute
theme_extensions │     
theme_extensions │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
theme_extensions │
theme_extensions │ 6 files inspected, 7 offenses detected, 5 offenses auto-correctable

╭─ error ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                              │
│  [blocks/carousel.liquid] Invalid tag 'schema': unknown key 'blocks'         │
│                                                                              │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯